# pytest-mock - Mock a function from a module

Tags: python, pytest

I have an util in my module `engine.py`, which is imported from another file:

```
from main.utils.string import get_random_string

def generate_random_string():
    return get_random_string()
```

In my test file:

```
def test_generate_random_string(mocker):
    mocker.patch('main.utils.string.get_random_string', return_value='123456')
```

However, it's still trying to use the real implementation of `string.get_random_string` instead of the mock that I've created, unless I change my `engine.py` to:

```
from main.utils import string

def generate_random_string():
    return string.get_random_string()
```

How can I achieve the mocking part without importing the whole `string` module to `engine.py`?

Comment: The upper part should also work. What error exactly are you getting when running test file?

Comment: It's trying to use the real code of `string.get_random_string`, instead of the mock that I've created

Comment: You should mock the function where you use it, not where it is declared. Try `mocker.patch('engine.get_random_string', return_value='123456')` instead. See [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for more details.

Comment: argh i did that, but I thought it wasn't the correct way to do it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have successfully achieved it by changing `mocker.patch('main.utils.string.get_random_string', return_value='123456')` to `mocker.patch('engine.get_random_string', return_value='123456')`.

Details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Answer (score 0):

While trying to patch a module function with

```
@patch('utils.collection_utils.min_object', return_value='mocked_min_object_result')
```

I had to change the import for my using class from

```
from utils.collection_utils import min_object
... 
min_object(...)
```

to

```
from utils import collection_utils
...
collection_utils.min_object(...)
```

Also note that using a patch might change the order of arguments for the test method. Instead of

```
@patch('utils.collection_utils.min_object', return_value='mocked_min_object')
def test_process_with_min_production_cost(sut):
```

then

```
@patch('utils.collection_utils.min_object', return_value='mocked_min_object')
def test_process_with_min_production_cost(patched_min_object, sut):
```